# How can I find all incongruous system solutions mod n?

Tags: number-theory

$\begin{array}{r}
x+y+z \equiv 1 \bmod 5 \\
2 x+4 y+3 z \equiv 1 \bmod 5
\end{array}$

I have this system and I want to find all incongruous system solutions.

Well, I know that

$x+y+z-1=5k_1$ and $2x+4y+3z-1=5k_2$.

Can I find the solutions before without taking $\bmod 5$?
I mean $x+5q,y+5q_1,z+5q_2$.

Comment: I think it's much easier to work entirely within mod 5. Your equations are mod 5, you want your answers mod 5. It makes sense to stay mod 5 all the way between. It isn't even that difficult: equations are solved with exactly the same methods you're used to. Just beware that division behaves a little differently.

Comment: Why would you want to *avoid* $\mod 5$?  $\mod 5$ was invented to make these systems easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is equivalent to this one:
$$
x+y+z\equiv 1\pmod5 \\
2y+z\equiv -1\pmod5
$$
for $-2$ times the first congruence added to the original second one yields the second congruence in this system; and $2$ times the first congruence added to the second one is the original congruence.

Solve the second one for $y, z$ by discussion or listing out all possibilities. Then let $x=1-y-z$ for these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it $\mod 5$.

$x \equiv 1 - y - z \pmod 5$ and

Substitute

$2x + 4y + 3z \equiv 1$

$2(1-y-z) + 4y + 3z \equiv 1$

$2 + 2y + z \equiv 1$

$z \equiv -1 -2y$.  And substitute back

And $x \equiv 1-y -(-1-2y) \equiv 2+y$.

So there are five classes of solutions.

$y \equiv 0; x \equiv 2; z\equiv 4$

$y\equiv 1; x\equiv 3; z \equiv  2$

$y \equiv 2; x\equiv 4; z \equiv 0$

$y \equiv 3; x\equiv 0; z\equiv 3$

$y\equiv 4; x\equiv 1; z\equiv 1$